# Translation: "유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이 가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽기 때문인데요"

Tags: meaning

I'm new Korean learner and now I saw this sentence in a paragraph.

> 요즘엔 일반 건물도 유리로 짓는 경우가 많습니다. 유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이 가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽기 때문인데요

Can you help me to translate "유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이 가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽기 때문인데요" into English? Because the sentence is too long so i can't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the middle bit first:

> 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이 가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽다

This means 'the appearance is beautiful, and many designs are possible, so the character of the building can easily come out'.

> 유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은

means "speaking about the increase in glass buildings,"

and then

> ...-기 때문인데요

means 'that's why'; 'that's the reason'

So the whole sentence:

> 유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이 가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽기 때문인데요

Means something like 'The increase in glass buildings is because they are beautiful, and it's possible to make a lot of different designs to allow the character of the building to come out".

It is a difficult sentence to me too. As you probably know, to break a sentence down, it helps to look for the conjunctions. 가능**해** is a conjunction but it's hard to spot!

Comment: @ThaiTrinh I'm not, I just have Koreans in my family who can help :) welcome to the site!

Comment: One additional point: "-인데요" is used here to connect this sentence to the next, so it's something like "The increase in glass buildings is (...blah blah...), **and** (now I'm going to tell something more about it)".

Answer (score 0):

유리 건물이 점점 늘어나는 것은 외관이 아름답고 다양한 디자인이
가능해 건물의 개성을 드러내기 쉽기 때문인데요

There are various designs for a beautiful appearance so that we can
express a character of building easily. Accordingly, buildings with
panes are increasing.